# Incorrect use of DISTINCT

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, distinct

I have a form view that displays the ListingID, PropertyID, ListingAgentID, SaleStatusID, EndListDate and AskingPrice from a database in SQL.

I have a DropDownList that displays the LastNames of agents that when selected it returns back the relevent information in the formView corresponding to the selection.

It's working, but the only problem is that each last name in the dropDownList is duplicated as they each have more than one listing. What I need it to do is when selecting one last name from the DropDownList it returns one value in the FormView, while being able to use paging to view different listings from that agent.

The code in the FormView is:

```
SELECT[ListingID], 
      [PropertyID], 
      [ListingAgentID], 
      [SaleStatusID], 
      [EndListDate], 
      [AskingPrice] 
FROM [Listings]
WHERE ([ListingID] = @ListingID)
```

The code in the DropDownList is:

```
SELECT Agents.LastName, 
       Listings.ListingID, 
       Listings.PropertyID, 
       Listings.ListingAgentID,
       Listings.SaleStatusID, 
       Listings.BeginListDate, 
       Listings.EndListDate,
       Listings.AskingPrice 
FROM Agents 
INNER JOIN Listings 
ON  Agents.AgentID = Listings.ListingAgentID
```

Where ever I try and put a DISTINCT function it returns an error or doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Agents.LastName FROM Agents INNER JOIN Listings ON Agents.AgentID = Listings.ListingAgentID

Comment: The distinct can only go after the select.  It will only provide distinctness across all columns you selected, not just one of the columns.  Therefore reducing the columns select to just the listing agent is the only way to get the distinct agent unless you can somehow aggregate all the other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dropdown all you need is an ID as value and the LastName to display.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Agents.LastName FROM Agents INNER JOIN Listings ON Agents.AgentID = Listings.ListingAgentID
```

Comment: ERROR DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ListingID'.

Comment: +1 don't forget to sort the results alphabetically for a nicer user XP...it'd be hard to sift through dozens (or hundreds) of last names if not correctly sorted

Comment: @AshleyKrynen that ERROR has nothing to do with your question!!!!!!!! You should accept the answer

Comment: @AshleyKrynen then post a separate question...you can't expect people to debug or fix the whole solution for you